# Django: get object with field/column based on another field/column?

Tags: mysql, django

Is it possible to get an object with a field that is related to another field of the same object?

For example I'd like to do:

```
class Transfer(models.Model):
    creation_time=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ttl=models.IntegerField(default=600)

alive_transfers = Transfer.objects.filter(creation_time__gt=time.time()-ttl)
```

Comment: Yes. [F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple datetime expressions you can use F filters:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model

From docs:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> Entry.objects.filter(mod_date__gt=F('pub_date') + timedelta(days=3))
```

If your filter involves a complex expression, I suggest using `extra` clause: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra

Of course this works well if you are sure about your DB backend.

Answer (score 0):

```py
#If you want to save that field, override the save method, something like this
class Transfer(models.Model):
    creation_time = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ttl = models.IntegerField(default=600)
    alive_transfers = models.IntegerField()   

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.alive_transfers = self.creation_time__gt=time.time()-self.ttl
    super(Transfer, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.


# If you want just get without saving, make an instance method to call in the views
class Transfer(models.Model):
    creation_time = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ttl = models.IntegerField(default=600)

    def _get_alive_transfers(self):
        return self.creation_time__gt=time.time()-self.ttl


# so in the views you call that method in an object instance, example:
alive_transfers = Transfer.objects.filter(pk=1)._get_alive_transfers()
```